# How to loop through JSON objects in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm new to Swift and I can't figure this out. I'm creating a simple quiz app where the questions are coming from a json file. I am able to successfully parse this data but I can't figure out how to loop through the json file to show each question. Currently, only the first question is being displayed and when an answer is selected, it shows the answer as correct/incorrect and nothing else. I would like for the next question to be populated from the json file once a user answers a question but I can't figure out how to do that. This is the code I have so far.

```
private func parseJSON() {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "quizQuestions", ofType: "txt") else { return }
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)

        guard let array = json as? [Any] else { return }

        for item in array {
            guard let quizObjects = item as? [String: Any] else { return }
            guard let questionNumber = quizObjects["id"] as? Int else { print("not an Int"); return }
            guard let question = quizObjects["question"] as? String else { return }
            guard let answerChoices = quizObjects["answerChoices"] as? [String] else { return }
            guard let correctAnswer = quizObjects["correctAnswer"] as? Int else { return }
        }
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I have included the loadNextQuestion function for you to see what I'm trying to do. Previously, I had all of the questions hard-coded in a swift object so this worked but now I am trying to pull from a json file. The main thing I'm struggling with is how to determine the current question and position in order to make this logic work.

```
func loadNextQuestion() {
    // Show next question
    if(currentQuestionPos + 1 < currentQuestion.count) {
        currentQuestionPos += 1
        currentQuestion = question
        setQuestion()

    }
    // If there are no more questions show the results
    else {

    }
}
```

Here is the json file I'm pulling from:

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"question": "What color is the sky?",
"answerChoices": ["Green", "White", "Blue", "Brown"],
"correctAnswer": 2
},

{
"id": 2,
"question": "What color is the grass?",
"answerChoices": ["Pink", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
"correctAnswer": 0
},

{
"id": 3,
"question": "Which of these has 8 legs?",
"answerChoices": ["Spider", "Lizard", "Cricket", "Snake"],
"correctAnswer": 0
},
]
```

Comment: You would be better off defining structs for your data and using `JSONDecoder` to parse the JSON data. There are countless tutorials on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, I would use the dependency [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to manage your JSON file so looping through your question bank is much easier.

One way to solve this would be to define a global variable to keep track of the state of your question. Something like:

```
var questionNum : Int = 0
```

As the user clicks to answer the question, add 1 to the variable. And use that to move through your JSON list. Connect your list with the UI variable so it'll change each time a user answers a question.

```
func moveToNextQuestion(){
  questionNum += 1
  questionLabel.text = question[questionNum]
}
```

Place the moveToNextQuestion function inside your button action.

Comment: Why use an external dependency when you could just use `Codable` for essentially a no-code solution

Answer (score 0):

To handle a json file, swift has the **Codable** protocol. Please see the code below, how I have created your json to array of object so that you can show your quiz view one by one by using index.
Playgound Code:

```
typealias Model = [ModelElement]
struct ModelElement : Codable {
    let id : Int?
    let question : String?
    let answerChoices : [String]?
    let correctAnswer : Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case id = "id"
        case question = "question"
        case answerChoices = "answerChoices"
        case correctAnswer = "correctAnswer"
    }
}

var json = """
[
{
"id": 1,
"question": "What color is the sky?",
"answerChoices": ["Green", "White", "Blue", "Brown"],
"correctAnswer": 2
},

{
"id": 2,
"question": "What color is the grass?",
"answerChoices": ["Pink", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
"correctAnswer": 0
},

{
"id": 3,
"question": "Which of these has 8 legs?",
"answerChoices": ["Spider", "Lizard", "Cricket", "Snake"],
"correctAnswer": 0
}
]
""".data(using: .utf8)

let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
let responseModels = try jsonDecoder.decode(Model.self, from: json!)

for item in responseModels {
    print(item.id)
}
```